# Why are my tables misaligned?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm developing a new page in our web application, but I am *really* not a web designer. In trying to keep it standard with our rather outdated design principles, we've got tables in tables in tables.

Ultimately, this page is comprised of a table with a single row containing two `<TD>` elements. In each `<TD>` is another table. The left column's table contains a bunch of rows and 4 columns per row. The right column's table has about 8 columns and about as many rows as the left. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm *mostly* happy with how the right hand side looks, except that they should be pushed more to the right but I guess I'll worry about that later. What I am concerned about is why everything is so scrunched up on the left and side. The drop down controls (created with Telerik's Kendo UI) are cut off, the little Information icon is beneath the drop downs even though there is no `<BR />` tag or anything.

The first few rows for the left column are written like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Admission</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Section B - ...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BB0700.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Some Text...</td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelFieldName).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbModelFieldName_Tab6", @class = "width-85" })) <img src="..\..\..\..\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BB0800.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Some Other Text...</td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelOtherFieldName).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbModelOtherFieldName_Tab6", @class = "width-85" })) <img src="..\..\..\..\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Section C - ...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C0100.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>More Text?</td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelMoreFields).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbModelMoreFields_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
            <img src="..\..\..\..\UDSMR.UDSCentral.Web\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Then the first few rows & columns from the right hand table are like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Three<img src="..\..\..\..\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>GG0130.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="textalign-right">A.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Some Text Field</td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeTextField).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbSomeTextField_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
        </td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeTextField2).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbSomeTextField2_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
        </td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeTextField3).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbSomeTextField3_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
            <img src="..\..\..\..\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="textalign-right">B.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Next Field</td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.NextField).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbNextField_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
        </td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.NextField2).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbNextField2_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
        </td>
        <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="textalign-center">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.NextField3).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbNextField3_Tab6", @class = "width-85" }))
            <img src="..\..\..\..\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Overall, the tables are pretty much defined the same way. Very little extra formatting via CSS, just mostly just plain old HTML with the Kendo controls instead of ASP.NET or 'vanilla' HTML controls.

I should note that the database is not correctly set up, so the model its trying to bind to doesn't exist but that shouldn't matter.

So I guess the problems I'm having:

- Why is there a large amount of padding / empty white-space at the top of the right columns?
- Why are my drop down menus being cut off on the left hand columns?
- Why is the (i) image displaying below the drop downs?

I've tried looking over similar webpages of ours that have an almost identical layout but I cannot identify what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Well, this is why (as you acknowledge) using tables within tables is outdated practice. There's no way to force two different tables to match up without lots of styling to fix widths, heights, and vertical alignments. If at all possible, you should try to move to a more modern layout rather than spending more time trying to fix this one.

Comment: @EdCottrell perhaps I'll look into it, but like I said I'm not a web designer at all. I've never been good at it, not with tables and not with divs. I just know tables haven't been the way to go since like 1995 lol. A third party just rewrote our software and I was really hoping they'd scrap all the tables but no such luck. So I thought I'd try to stick with it for this 1 page that needs to be added :(

Comment: You could just look at frontend frameworks like bootstrap. It's easy to understand and not that hard to master

Comment: @FKutsche I don't really have the authority or flexibility to just pick up random libraries or frameworks to use, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, you'll spend less time doing it without so much tables. The best is to use some framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) but I think you can make what you want without changing your approach too much putting the left and right table inside a div.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
<div style="width: 50%;float:left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td><td>LeftTable</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%;float:left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th><th>Col6</th><th>Col7</th><th>Col8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td><td>RightTable</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This make both tables fit the same space. You can change de percentage of the divs so one is wider than the other.

Comment: Thanks Ion, I'll try this. Hopefully it works; I didn't realize it could be as simple as you've made it seem.

Comment: This helped fix the issue of the weird whitespace at the top, but now there's an extremely large gap of white space between the two tables and the drop downs on the left are still cut off. But it's absolutely an improvment, I'll continue to mess around with it from here. Thanks again.

Comment: The large gap between the tables is because both of them have the same width (50% each of them). Try to change that values (for example 30% and 70% respectively) until the tables use the space you want. About the dropdowns... I'm not sure, I must admit that the code you have put is a bit confusing for me, xD. I think they have a fixed width or something like that so they cant fit inside the cell. Try to remove all the classes so you can se the result before any css is applied.